# Avoid locking on single threaded async

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Let's say I have the following struct:

```rust
struct Time {
    hour: u8,
    minute: u8
}

impl Time {
    pub fn set_time(&mut self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
        self.hour = hour;
        self.minute = minute;
    }
}
```

On a multithreaded program, having a mutable reference to it shared across multiple threads could cause race conditions, but on a single-threaded one that can't happen (there is no way for the task to yield inside set_time).

Is there any way to avoid having to use locks in such a situation?

Here is an example where two tasks are running on a single thread and could share the mutable reference without a problem:

```rust
use tokio::join;

struct Time {
  hour: u8,
  minute: u8
}

impl Time {
  pub fn set_time(&mut self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
      self.hour = hour;
      self.minute = minute;
  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut runtime_builder = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread();
  runtime_builder.enable_time();
  let runtime = runtime_builder.build().unwrap();
  runtime.block_on(async_main());
}

async fn async_main() {
  let mut time = Time {hour: 0, minute: 0};

  join!(
    task_1(&mut time),
    task_2(&mut time) // <- Rust wont allow this
  );
}

async fn task_1(time: &mut Time) {
  loop {
    // Do something
    tokio::task::yield_now();
  }
}

async fn task_2(time: &mut Time) {
  loop {
    // Do something
    tokio::task::yield_now();
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code does not use any locks, and it looks like it works just fine. Could you provide a bit more details what problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Exclusive ref are by definition exclusive in single and multihreaded context. This condition is required to guarantee memory safety, not only absence of data races.

Comment: I'm talking about async code, where two tasks can share a reference but as they are running on a single thread, they can't interrupt each other in an unsafe way (they have to wither yield or await).

Comment: @Jerboas86 If there is no way, then that is the answer. But unless rustc has the ability to optimize this, it seems to me that a lot of unnecessary locking is needed to do something that could be done without locks.

Comment: Looks like you could make this work by wrapping your struct in a RefCell

Comment: if you want both aliasing and mutability, you need to use interior mutability pattern. this pattern can be implemented on data structure that are lock free.

Comment: It seems like Cells could be a solution. But they still rely either on locking or on runtime checks. Another solution could be having the runtime provide some kind of storage. That way there is a single owner of the mutable reference, that tasks could access. In this case, switching to a multithreaded runtime would make the runtime storage unavailable, forcing us to use proper locking.

Comment: You can try to use Atomic types which provides lock free interior mutability for "simple" data as u8.

Comment: `Cell` does not use locking.

Answer (score 1):

Mutable reference aliasing is never allowed by the borrow checker. This is one of conditions that the borrow checker enforces to guarantee memory safety at compile time.

This is the reason why the following code doesn't compile. There is 2 mutable references at the same time.

```rust
  join!(
    task_1(&mut time), // <- first mutable reference
    task_2(&mut time) // <- second mutable reference ERROR
  );
```

This rule is not specific to multithreaded context.

In the other hand, immutable reference aliasing is allowed by the borrow checker. but the following code would not compile because we can't mutate a field behind a shared reference.

```rust
use tokio::join;

struct Time {
  hour: u8,
  minute: u8
}

impl Time {
  pub fn set_time(&self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
      self.hour = hour; // Error
      self.minute = minute; // Error
  }
}

[...]

async fn async_main() {
  let mut time = Time {hour: 0, minute: 0};

  join!(
    task_1(&time),
    task_2(&time)
  );
}

[...]

}
```

To have both aliasing and mutation capabilities, you need to use the interior mutability pattern.

Interior mutability:
"A type has interior mutability if its internal state can be changed through a shared reference to it. This goes against the usual requirement that the value pointed to by a shared reference is not mutated." ([see rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/interior-mutability.html))

There is several types which implement interior mutability pattern:

- `Cell`
- `RefCell`
- Atomics kind
- `Mutex`
- `RwLock`

with single threaded runtime, you can use either `RefCell` or `Cell`

With `RefCell<T>`, The rules still applies but at runtime instead of compile time. With a single threaded runtime, `RefCell` allows us to mutate shared reference in separate task, since there is no parallelism involved.

```rust
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use tokio::join;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Time {
    hour: RefCell<u8>,
    minute: RefCell<u8>,
}

impl Time {
    pub fn set_time(&self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
        *self.hour.borrow_mut() = hour; 
        *self.minute.borrow_mut() = minute;
    }
}

async fn task_1(time: &Time) {
    time.set_time(11, 54);
    println!("Task 1: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
}

async fn task_2(time: &Time) {
    time.set_time(8, 12);
    println!("Task 2: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
}

fn main() {
    let mut runtime_builder = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread();
    runtime_builder.enable_time();
    let runtime = runtime_builder.build().unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async {
        let time = Time {
            hour: RefCell::new(0),
            minute: RefCell::new(0),
        };

        let _ = join!(task_1(&time), task_2(&time));
    });
}
```

[based on trentcl suggestion]

If you want to avoid the cost of runtime check, you can use `Cell<T>`. The API is pretty convenient when T is Copy.

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use tokio::join;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Time {
    hour: Cell<u8>,
    minute: Cell<u8>,
}

impl Time {
    pub fn set_time(&self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
        self.hour.replace(hour); 
        self.minute.replace(minute);
    }
}

async fn task_1(time: &Time) {
    time.set_time(11, 54);
    println!("Task 1: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
}

async fn task_2(time: &Time) {
    time.set_time(8, 12);
    println!("Task 2: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
}

fn main() {
    let mut runtime_builder = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_current_thread();
    runtime_builder.enable_time();
    let runtime = runtime_builder.build().unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async {
        let time = Time {
            hour: Cell::new(0),
            minute: Cell::new(0),
        };

        let _ = join!(task_1(&time), task_2(&time));
    });
}
```

With multithreaded runtime, you can use atomics kind, `Mutex`, `RwLock`, and channel messaging.

If we take the specific case of `AtomicU8`, this type provides interior mutability and its `store` method is lock-free (at least on x86).

by using `AtomicU8`, we can aliased and mutate our `Time` struct with no data race, and no blocking.

`AtomicU8` is Sync and Send, but we need to satisfy 'static bound for `tokio::spawn`, so taking a shared ref is not an option. We need to wrap the structure into an `Arc`.

```rust
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicU8, Ordering};
use tokio::join;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Time {
    hour: AtomicU8,
    minute: AtomicU8,
}

impl Time {
    pub fn set_time(&self, hour: u8, minute: u8) {
        self.hour.store(hour, Ordering::SeqCst); // <-- mutation OK
        self.minute.store(minute, Ordering::SeqCst); // <-- mutation OK
    }
}

async fn task_1(time: Arc<Time>) {
    time.set_time(11, 54);
    println!("Task 1: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
    
}

async fn task_2(time: Arc<Time>) {
    time.set_time(8, 12);
    println!("Task 2: {:?}", time);
    tokio::task::yield_now().await;
}

fn main() {
    let mut runtime_builder = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread();
    runtime_builder.enable_time();
    let runtime = runtime_builder.build().unwrap();
    runtime.block_on(async {
        let time = Arc::new(Time {
            hour: AtomicU8::new(0),
            minute: AtomicU8::new(0),
        });

        let h1 = tokio::spawn(task_1(time.clone()));
        let h2 = tokio::spawn(task_2(time));
        

        let _ = join!(
            h1, // <-- aliasing Ok
            h2 // <-- aliasing Ok
        );
    });
}
```

Comment: You can use `Cell<u8>` in this case, since OP specified they are using a single-threaded executor.